# Transcrypt is a compiler that translates Python into JavaScript ahead-of-time and dont working with sqlite3?

Tags: python, transcrypt

I try to execute command python `-m transcrypt -b -m -n mr_index.py`
and failed on code's string `"import sqlite3"`. Why?

> C:\Users\Legion\Downloads\meterrhyme-master>python -m transcrypt -b -m -n mr_index.py
> Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.7.16
> Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0
> Saving target code in: C:/Users/Legion/Downloads/meterrhyme-master/_*target_*/org.transcrypt._*runtime_*.js
> Error while compiling (offending file last):
> File 'mr_index', line 5, namely:
> Import error, can't find any of:
> C:/Users/Legion/Downloads/meterrhyme-master/sqlite3.py
> C:/Users/Legion/Downloads/meterrhyme-master/sqlite3.js
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/lib/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/sqlite3.py
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/lib/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/sqlite3.js
> C:/Users/Legion/Downloads/meterrhyme-master/sqlite3.py
> C:/Users/Legion/Downloads/meterrhyme-master/sqlite3.js
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/sqlite3.py
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/sqlite3.js
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/lib/site-packages/sqlite3.py
> C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/lib/site-packages/sqlite3.js
> Aborted

Answer (score 0):

Transcrypt can only transpile pure Python code and as such wont work with most 3rd party libraries that utilize C extensions.  It is intended to act as a bridge between Python code and the JavaScript world, mainly to create code that will run in a web browser and be able to utilize JavaScript libraries.

If you are using Node to run the transpiled Python code, you can use the [JavaScript SQLite library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) instead, but still code to it using Python.